# Strip seconds and milliseconds from System.currentTimeMillis value

Tags: java, time

Suppose I have a `System.currentTimeMillis()` value as a `long` number.

How do I modify it to match the instant when last minute started? I.e., zero out seconds and milliseconds.

I would prefer to not use magic constants. Using `java.time` is fine.

Comment: Couldn't you just truncate it? Or is that not what you want.

Comment: Could you use a `Calendar` object instead?

Comment: Are you okay assuming an idealized day? No leap seconds, etc.?

Comment: Couldn't you just divide it by `60L * 1000L`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the answers recommending `java.time`, but it can be done yet simpler as in those answers:

```
    long lastWholeMinute = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli();
```

This just gave `1517940060000`. Of course, if it makes sense for you to keep the `Instant` object, by all means do that rather than converting to a naked primitive `long`.

If your `long` value was one you had stored rather than the time now, it’s quite similar:

```
    long someEpochMilliValue = 1_517_941_234_567L;
    long lastWholeMinute = Instant.ofEpochMilli(someEpochMilliValue)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
            .toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: ***Nice***. Doesn't get a lot semantically clearer than `.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)`

Answer (score 3):

Using `java.time` is *probably* the **easiest** way. You could use `withNano` and `withSecond`, like

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime zdt = java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().withNano(0).withSecond(0);
long millis = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Seems like this is neither starting nor ending where the OP asked it to...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Missed the (as a "long"). I'll fix it.

Comment: It was supposed to be seconds and millis, not minutes and seconds!

Comment: ...and isn't the starting point supposed to be a `long` too? Or @alamar do you not care, so long as you end up with one? (Re minutes and seconds - that's an easy fix to make...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had to eat lunch. :)

Comment: :-) Not understanding the downvote on this *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value is in milliseconds, ***if*** we assume an idealized day (no leap seconds, etc.), then given `l` you could do it by simply removing the value of `l % 60000L` from it. I realize that's a magic constant, but it's truly a constant, there are always going to be 60,000 milliseconds in a minute. I'd give it symbolic name:

```
private static long SIXTY_SECONDS_IN_MS = 60000L;
```

and not worry about it. Then it's:

```
long l = /*...your number...*/;
l = l - (l % SIXTY_SECONDS_IN_MS);
```

Why this works: The Epoch value is from midnight Jan 1st 1970, and so at 0L, 60000L, 120000L, etc., the seconds and milliseconds of an idealized day based on that value are 0. So we use the remainder operator (`%`) to isolate the part of the value that would remain if we divided by 60000L and remove it. Thus the resulting value, again assuming idealized days, has 0 for seconds and milliseconds. It also works across timezones if we assume all timezones are going to be at whole-minute offsets to UTC. I've only ever heard of timezones that were multiples of hours or half-hours offset from UTC ("GMT plus five hours", "GMT plus 5.5 hours"), never (say) "GMT plus five hours seven minutes and 20 seconds". (And indeed, the standard notation for timezome offsets, `+0600` or similar, only includes hours and minutes, not fractional minutes.)

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/TQhuWb):

```
import java.time.*;

public class Example
{
    private static long SIXTY_SECONDS_IN_MS = 60000L;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        l = l - (l % SIXTY_SECONDS_IN_MS);
        System.out.println("l = " + l);

        // Checking the result
        LocalDateTime dt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(l).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(dt);
        System.out.println(dt.getSecond()); // 0
        System.out.println(dt.getNano());   // 0
    }
}
```

Still, though, if that constant violates the terms of the question such that you think I shouldn't have answered, let me know and I'll delete the answer. :-)

Comment: @alamar: Yeah, I flagged that up. But as I say above, it's not going to change. Give it a symbolic name and move on. :-)